# IoC configurations - one file/assembly in solution or one file per executing assembly?

Tags: dependency-injection, architecture, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, software-design

We're wondering what the best practise for registering types in a IoC-Container is.

What would be arguments for and against the following principles:

#### Principle 1: Only one Assembly my.project.DependencyInjection

- Seperate assembly for dependency injection
- One class (f.e. `UnityConfig.cs`) where all types of the whole solution are registered
- my.project.DependencyInjection references alot of projects to register their types

#### Principle 2: A IoC container configuration class per executing assembly

- Every executing assembly has their own `UnityConfig.cs` file
- Only the needed types of this assembly are registered in the respective `UnityConfig.cs` file

What's your stance in this?

Thanks in advance for your opinions and arguments

Comment: See the concept of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my Answer

```
Principle 2: A IoC container configuration class per executing assembly

Every executing assembly has their own UnityConfig.cs file
Only the needed types of this assembly are registered in the respective UnityConfig.cs file
```

The reason being, Dependencies are or should be injected at the run-time, so the responsibility of configuring what to inject should live at the top level component/executable, ie in mvc/web-api/wcf/exe.

Also with this approach each project can differ in DI tool, config etc etc.